# Which is a proper pronoun: you or we?

Tags: pronouns

I was wondering whether "You run a large chance" should be corrected into "We run a large chance" because he said "all six of us or all five of us,"  not "all six of you or all five of you." That is, the one who deals with the risk of "all of us getting it" is "we,"  not "you." Who is the reporter referring to when he says "you"?
This comes at 0:30 in the NBC News clip https://archive.org/download/KNTV_20200526_003000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt/KNTV_20200526_003000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt.mp4?t=1080/1140&ignore=x.mp4

> "You run a large chance of all six of us or all five of us getting it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You" is often used as kind of generic pronoun that doesn't necessarily refer to the person or people being addressed.

For example, even though I don't know whether you have ever been to Times Square I could tell you something like, "you often see really crazy people at Times Square". I don't mean you, Ji Hyun Lee, I mean anybody who goes to Times Square.

In this case, "you" can refer to anybody who is concerned with the success of the space mission, and would be impacted in the event the astronauts catch covid.